# Open Refine: Open Project Issue

Tags: openrefine, google-refine

I am an Open Refine user. I use this tools with RDF extension.  I have created a number of RDF projects. Each time I open this tool, I find my existing projects under Open Refine's  "Open Project" option. Two days ago I updated my computer's Java with the latest version. Now when I click "Open Project" option it shows empty. It says no existing project.  Also "RDF Extension" is not available. How can I find my previous RDF projects? Please let me know.  I had some important projects, and I really need those. Any help will be highly appreciated.